# Database error in creating blog using django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, blogs

Am trying to create simple blog using django.
At first,i created database with the command

> python manage.py syncdb

when i try to save blog post,i get the following error

> DatabaseError: table blog_app_post has no column named body

models.py code :

```
 from django.db import models
    from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

        class Post(models.Model):
            title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
            body = models.TextField()
            created = models.DateTimeField()
            tags = TaggableManager()
            def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

but the column  named body is actually created in the Db.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "blog_app_post" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "body" text NOT NULL,
    "created" datetime NOT NULL
)
```

what does this error mean and anyone would propose a solution for this?

Comment: Would you please run `manage.py sql <app_name>`, for us, and show us the output, it would help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you changed the structure of your posts data structure. What you need to do now is delete the schema for your previous table and paste in the new one.

You can avoid problems like this by using migration managers like `south`.

So, in order to solve this, run `manage.py sql <app_name>`, then you simply copy the latest SQL table on the list, the first one that is printed. Then you simply `maange.py dbshell` and then just paste and run the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

How do you say that it's created, you checking it using `python manage.py sqlall`?

Did you add field `body` after running syncdb initially. In that case you will have to use a migration.